# MySQL LIKE not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am not getting the expected search result from my code , This is a segment from my SQL Table

```
        Nom      Description 

        41099    Screen truck Hire for Northern Racing
        41100    Dry Hire - Screen
        41101    Dry Hire - Kit
        41102    Screen Truck Hire for chester / Bangor Dee
        41103    Blackburn Digiboard Backup DVD-DO NOT USE
```

This is my PHP code and I am getting the expected results until I search for 'chester' , when I get no result . Can anyone tell me what is going wrong please ?

PHP Code to retrun XML Data

```
   echo '<sites>'  ; 


    $condition = "Description LIKE '%chester%' ";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jbe_nominal_codes WHERE $condition")  ;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$nom  = $row['nominal'] ;
if (!$nom) { $nom= "0000" ; } ; 

$des  = $row['Description'] ;
if (!$des) { $des= "No Description" ; } ; 

    echo "<NameSearch> " ; 

echo '<nominal>';
echo $nom;
echo '</nominal>'; 

echo '<Description>' ;
echo $des ; 
echo '</Description>' ;


   echo "</NameSearch> " ; 
   } ;
```

Comment: Do be extremely careful about [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You shouldn't even be using `mysql_query` at all unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: i dont think it should be 'wrong' but that / looks suspicious... if you remove that from your original data - then does the query work?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I agree with @Randy about the slash being suspicious. Also make sure you are using correct capitalization.  From your example it seems you are, but just verify.

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason why this isnt working, I would however test the query in mysql client to see if it returned what I expected.

Comment: try char (`) on Description like this $condition = "\`Description\` LIKE '%chester%' ";

Comment: See if chester is really stored in the database as chester or just maybe in some different encoding from a copy paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good practice is to extend your mysql_ statement.

> mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jbe_nominal_codes WHERE $condition")or
>   die(mysql_error());

if a error is thrown, you know there is something wrong in your query and you will get some hints from the error, if not, could it be that chester is not in the your db table at all?

like previously said, you should take note of mysqli and PDO and why you should not use mysql_ anymore. [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)